# oh-my-zsh throws rrror when trying to access zsh profile in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: zsh, macos, oh-my-zsh

Trying to access either .zshrc or .zprofile doesn't work (it creates a new file).

Trying to access the it with  `~/.zshrc` throws the same error.

From my understanding I must have messed up one of my PATH variables (unsure of how this works, I am still a beginner).

Or that something is wrong with my oh-my-zsh configuration?

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enter `~/.zshrc`, and assuming you've made `~/.zshrc` executable (which it shouldn't need to be as it's not meant to be *executed*), then it's executed as if it was a script.

Since that file will not have a `#! /path/to/interpreter -` she-bang, since again, it's not meant to be executed, it will be interpreted by a new invocation of `sh`.

On your system, `sh` seems to be `bash` which explains why you're getting bash-style error messages (bash barks on the parts of the code that are zsh-specific and that it doesn't understand like the `() {...}` anonymous function or the zsh-specific `autoload` builtin).

`~/.zshrc` is interpreted automatically on startup of interactive `zsh` invocations. If you want to have your current `zsh` shell interpret it *again*, you can do (csh-style):

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Or (sh-style):

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

Or simply restart `zsh` with:

```
exec zsh
```